# Spin: error, the version of spin that generated this pan.c assumed a different wordsize (4 iso 8)

Tags: gcc, formal-verification, model-checking, spin, promela

I am using Windows O.S and in Cygwin i type: `wish -f ispin.tcl` to open the ispin interface.
I open a file `test.pml` which contains:

```
byte state = 2;

proctype A()
{   (state == 1) -> state = 3
}

proctype B()
{   state = state - 1
}

init
{   run A(); run B()
}
```

After that, I run it using the random way with seed = 123. The results are printed in output without problems:

```
  0:    proc  - (:root:) creates proc  0 (:init:)
Starting A with pid 1
  1:    proc  0 (:init::1) creates proc  1 (A)
  1:    proc  0 (:init::1) test.pml:12 (state 1)    [(run A())]
Starting B with pid 2
  2:    proc  0 (:init::1) creates proc  2 (B)
  2:    proc  0 (:init::1) test.pml:12 (state 2)    [(run B())]
  3:    proc  2 (B:1) test.pml:8 (state 1)  [state = (state-1)]
  4:    proc  1 (A:1) test.pml:4 (state 1)  [((state==1))]
  4:    proc  2 (B:1) terminates
  5:    proc  1 (A:1) test.pml:4 (state 2)  [state = 3]
  5:    proc  1 (A:1) terminates
  5:    proc  0 (:init::1) terminates
3 processes created
```

The problem appears when I try to verify this model. The result of the verification is:

```
verification result:
spin -a  test.pml
gcc -DMEMLIM=1024 -O2 -DXUSAFE -DSAFETY -DNOCLAIM -w -o pan pan.c
./pan -m10000 
Pid: 3952
spin: error, the version of spin that generated this pan.c assumed a different wordsize (4 iso 8)
```

How can I solve this? I searched on the internet but I couldn't find something to help me.

Note: I haven't changed any verification property:
[image: ispin_interface_verification_properties]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution to the above error was to install [Cygwin for 32-bit versions of Windows](https://cygwin.com/install.html) even if my laptop is 64-bit. This is because the [executable of spin](http://spinroot.com/spin/Bin/index.html) exists only for Windows 32-bit, so they have to match as I understood.

After the installation of Cygwin (`gcc`, `cpp`, `make`), we move the `spin`, `ispin` and `test` files to the new Cygwin folder (`C:\cygwin\`).

When we try to run and verify again the model, without needing any other modifications, we can see the correct output with no errors:

```
verification result:
spin -a  test.promela
gcc -DMEMLIM=1024 -O2 -DXUSAFE -DSAFETY -DNOCLAIM -w -o pan pan.c
./pan -m10000 
Pid: 6304
pan:1: assertion violated 0 (at depth 6)
pan: wrote test.promela.trail

(Spin Version 6.4.5 -- 1 January 2016)
Warning: Search not completed
    + Partial Order Reduction

Full statespace search for:
    never claim             - (not selected)
    assertion violations    +
    cycle checks        - (disabled by -DSAFETY)
    invalid end states  +

State-vector 20 byte, depth reached 6, errors: 1
        7 states, stored
        0 states, matched
        7 transitions (= stored+matched)
        0 atomic steps
hash conflicts:         0 (resolved)

Stats on memory usage (in Megabytes):
    0.000   equivalent memory usage for states (stored*(State-vector + overhead))
    0.292   actual memory usage for states
   64.000   memory used for hash table (-w24)
    0.343   memory used for DFS stack (-m10000)
   64.539   total actual memory usage



pan: elapsed time 0.002 seconds
To replay the error-trail, goto Simulate/Replay and select "Run"
```